# C++ dynamic memory allocation is slower in OpenMP, even for non-parallel sections of code

Tags: c++, openmp

I have run into a rather frustrating problem with OpenMP: it seems that if OpenMP is used in parallel mode somewhere in the code (for more than one thread), then dynamic memory allocation/de-allocation becomes slower even in non-parallel portions of code. Here is an example program (just an illustration):

```
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        // Just to get OpenMP going
    }

    double wtime0, wtime;
    wtime0 = omp_get_wtime();

    double **stuff;
    const int N = 1000000;

    stuff = new double*[N];
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++) stuff[i] = new double;
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++) *(stuff[i]) = sqrt(i);
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++) delete[] stuff[i];
    delete[] stuff;

    wtime = omp_get_wtime() - wtime0;
    cout << "Total CPU time: " << wtime << endl;
}
```

When I run this code with one thread on my laptop (which is an Intel Core 2 Duo), I get a CPU time of 0.093. On the other hand, if I run it with two threads, the CPU time increases to 0.13. The more pointer allocations there are, the worse the discrepancy becomes. In the above code, if I were to replace "stuff" by a simple array, e.g.

```
    double stuff2[N];
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++) stuff2[i] = sqrt(i);
```

then there is no discrepancy. Can someone tell me why this problem exists when pointers are allocated/de-allocated, even though it's not done in parallel? The reason why this is a problem is because in the real code I am working with, dynamic memory allocation is essential. There are sections that can be sped up by running in parallel, but (with two threads versus one) this is more than overcompensated by the fact that the memory allocation/de-allocation is slowed down considerably, even in the non-parallel sections. If someone with extensive OpenMP experience can tell me how to get around this problem I would really appreciate it. (Worst case scenario, I can just use MPI instead, but I would love it if this can be solved within OpenMP.)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Memory allocation is very expensive in general. In a parallel environment it can get worse as they may contend for the same locks over the same internal data structures. If you're serious about performance, move the allocations to a higher level or get rid of them completely. Quite often, there's no free lunch and it's difficult to have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is concievable. In general, one should avoid naive dynamic allocations in multi-threading anvironment, as there is a single lock there. MT-aware allocators provide a much better performance and should be preferred in allocation-heavy scenarios.
This is exactly why I always scowl down on code here which just uses vectors or strings or shared pointers as a class members without letting users to specify allocation policy.

Comment: Interesting...I hadn't heard of MT-aware allocators (I am only a humble physicist, not a computer scientist). Is there a pre-made allocator you might recommend? I came upon jemalloc, but don't know if that is one of the better ones. Also if you know of a particularly good paper/article which discusses this issue, I would appreciate that as well. Thanks.

Comment: The wide-used solution is tcmalloc from Google. I myself prefer mt_allocator from g++ - it is a C++-conformant allocator. I am not aware of any articles, but I am sure if you just type tcmalloc in your favorite search engine, you will see alot.

Comment: I'd try TBB malloc, TCMalloc and/or JEMalloc. PTMalloc is good but not designed for this usage.

Comment: You can experiment with TBB malloc without even recompiling. See https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Automically_Replacing_malloc.htm

Comment: Compiling with tcmalloc fixed this problem completely. I still don't fully understand how it fixed it, but I am content to know that it's fixed and move on. Thanks for letting me know about this!

Comment: Well, you might express your gratitude in form of upvoting and accepting the answer. You see, I am kinda short on reputation :)